# How to solve some countries missing and misplaced issue in tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I made a population density map with `tmap` package.
However after merging my own data to the World@data in tmap, I found USA in my map is missing, and Vietnam data was misplaced in the place of USA. Rwanda in place of Russia. Checked the merged data, seemed that nothing went wrong. My code:

```
df$iso3 <- countrycode(df$country, 'name', 'iso3c')
#Remove the NAs in orginal datasetm, there are three NAs in World@data
df <- na.omit(df)

data(World)
str(World, max.level = 2)
World@data <- merge(World@data, df, by.x = "iso_a3", by.y = "iso3", all.x = TRUE)
map <- tm_shape(World)+
       tm_polygons("1950",
                  title = "Pop Class",
                  palette = "Blues",
                  contrast = 0.7,
                  border.col = "gray30",
                  id = "name")+
      tm_text("iso_a3", size = "AREA", col = "gray30", root =3)+
      tm_format_World()+
      tm_style_gray()

current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")
map111_6
```

I had a public dataset from wpp2015 which is not exactly same as my dataset but will provide an intuition of my data frame structure.

```
 dput(df) <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 21L, 190L, 28L, 29L, 146L, 31L, 19L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 32L, 37L, 201L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 134L, 49L, 58L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 22L, 59L, 61L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 69L, 70L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 60L, 78L, 80L, 79L, 203L, 81L, 82L, 108L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 93L, 44L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 51L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 105L, 107L, 57L, 173L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 115L, 116L, 113L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 124L, 45L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 136L, 141L, 174L, 142L, 144L, 145L, 160L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 54L, 9L, 150L, 231L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 158L, 138L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 89L, 214L, 171L, 172L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 202L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 233L, 189L, 191L, 194L, 241L, 200L, 196L, 205L, 237L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 223L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 212L, 66L, 224L, 41L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 30L, 229L, 230L, 232L, 180L, 239L, 240L, 238L, 143L, 117L, 2L, 112L, 156L, 63L, 72L, 159L, 62L, 140L, 155L, 197L, 234L, 36L, 38L, 193L, 192L, 235L, 64L, 157L, 199L, 236L, 12L, 135L, 195L, 161L, 10L, 114L, 204L, 118L, 137L, 169L, 122L, 123L, 228L, 92L, 139L, 39L, 198L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Africa", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Asia", "Australia", "Australia/New Zealand", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Caribbean", "Central African Republic", "Central America", "Central Asia", "Chad", "Channel Islands", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Dem. People's Rep. of Korea", "Dem. Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Eastern Africa", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Europe", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Europe", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "High-income countries", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Dem. Republic", "Latin America and the Caribbean", "Latvia", "Least developed countries", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Less developed regions", "Less developed regions, excluding China", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", "Low-income countries", "Lower-middle-income countries", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Melanesia", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Micronesia (Fed. States of)", "Middle-income countries", "Middle Africa", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "More developed regions", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Northern Africa", "Northern America", "Northern Europe", "Norway", "Oceania", "Oman", "Other less developed countries", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Polynesia", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Samoa", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South-Central Asia", "South-Eastern Asia", "South Africa", "South America", "South Sudan", "Southern Africa", "Southern Asia", "Southern Europe", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Tajikistan", "TFYR Macedonia", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United Republic of Tanzania", "United States of America", "United States Virgin Islands", "Upper-middle-income countries", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "Viet Nam", "Western Africa", "Western Asia", "Western Europe", "Western Sahara", "World", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), `1950` = c(7752.118, 1263.171, 8872.247, 4354.882, 46.301, 2895.997, 17150.335, 8177.344, 6936.445, 79.088, 115.614, 37894.68, 1353.506, 210.995, 8628.489, 176.795, 3089.649, 2661.293, 412.533, 53974.726, 68.918, 89.793, 48.001, 7250.999, 17527.243, 2308.923, 7745.003, 4432.716, 4466.498, 13736.997, 178.066, 1326.653, 8075.81, 2502.314, 6142.899, 544112.923, 7561.863, 12340.899, 156.334, 15.141, 807.726, 12183.661, 959.489, 3850.295, 5919.997, 494.014, 8902.619, 2255.221, 4268.27, 2364.65, 3470.162, 2199.897, 225.536, 18128.034, 1142.15, 1100.998, 288.993, 4008.299, 41879.607, 25.479, 60.268, 62.001, 473.3, 3527.004, 271.372, 931.926, 69786.246, 4980.878, 33.05, 7566.002, 76.676, 209.999, 59.65, 3146.073, 3093.651, 406.562, 3221.277, 1487.235, 1973.998, 9337.723, 142.656, 376325.205, 69543.319, 17119.263, 5719.191, 2913.093, 1257.971, 46598.602, 2630.131, 1402.896, 82199.47, 6702.996, 448.861, 6076.757, 10549.469, 19211.386, 152.25, 1740, 1682.916, 1334.618, 733.942, 1949, 930.026, 1113.382, 2567.402, 296.001, 196.482, 4083.554, 2953.871, 6109.907, 73.715, 4708.425, 311.997, 222.001, 660.491, 493.254, 28012.558, 780.2, 2341.003, 394.738, 8985.99, 6313.29, 456.418, 485.274, 8483.321, 10027.047, 100.184, 38.066, 64.824, 47.695, 1908.001, 1294.993, 2559.703, 37859.745, 3265.278, 32, 37542.38, 859.66, 1708.192, 1473.245, 7727.735, 18580.487, 24824.013, 8416.969, 535.429, 433.398, 2218, 24.999, 248.111, 16236.292, 102798.657, 2186.187, 82.783, 67, 60, 3121.336, 2476.638, 6732.256, 36.322, 1944.001, 1022.098, 3436.574, 24809.903, 1473.094, 2264.081, 13683.162, 2746.854, 28069.737, 2582.929, 5733.944, 13.766, 214.999, 273, 7009.913, 4668.088, 3413.329, 1531.502, 20710.356, 1395.458, 47.22, 645.628, 69.59, 3605.31, 21238.496, 1211, 5158.193, 37297.652, 1254.444, 20897.237, 50616.012, 102.235, 7649.766, 157813.04, 26.795, 4284.457, 2238.506, 6945.397, 5481.977, 82.102, 4402.32, 2316.95, 2525149.312, 812988.79, 1712160.522, 228901.723, 168843.911, 171614.868, 666585.791, 549089.107, 12681.946, 66922.702, 26400.57, 49221.876, 15587.911, 70768.664, 17075.654, 38028.823, 164900.344, 511574.182, 50957.44, 220170.535, 78029.913, 108632.979, 142255.68, 10085.345, 2199.497, 113739.434, 1516435.967, 1394017.757, 195724.555, 179679.847, 1158315.256, 155.093, 242.011, 130103.438, 768893.01, 824937.314, 800383.367, 1593830.324, 18130.895, 493443.287)), .Names = c("name", "1950"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -241L))
```

Can anyone help review my scripts? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `World` object is a specific, rather complex object, so it's probably not a great idea to modify it's data directly with `merge`... better to use the `append_data` function in the `tmaptools` package...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
country  pop_density
Afghanistan  1
Angola  2
Albania  3
Argentina  5
Armenia  6
France  7
Australia  8
")


# your origin value should be `'country.name'`, not `'name'`

library(countrycode)
df$iso3 <- countrycode(df$country, 'country.name', 'iso3c')

library(tmap)
data(World)

# the `World` object is a specific, rather complex object, so it's probably not
# a great idea to modify it's data directly with `merge`... better to use the
# `append_data` function in the `tmaptools` package...

library(tmaptools)
World <- append_data(World, df, key.shp = "iso_a3", key.data = "iso3", 
                     ignore.na = T)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("pop_density", title = "Pop Class", palette = "Blues", 
              contrast = 0.7, border.col = "gray30", id = "name") +
  tm_text("iso_a3", size = "AREA", col = "gray30", root = 3)
```